# /sbin/sh: pm: not found

Tags: adb, 4.1-jelly-bean, custom-roms, installation

I was trying to install apk files from `adb`. I used the command `adb install <app-name>.apk` command. But it returned

> /sbin/sh: pm: not found

But if I login to the shell with `adb shell` and do `which pm`, it returns

```
/system/bin/pm
```

But still I can't install apk using `pm`. If I do `pm install /sdcard/app-name.apk` It returns same `/sbin/sh: pm: not found` error.

`whoami` returns strange things.

```
whoami: unknown uid 0
```

But If I become `root` and install using `pm` it works just fine! What could be the problem and How do I solve it?

I'm using a custom ROM ([WolfRom v2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/sola-development/rom-wolf-romv2-t2424632)) on Xperia Sola Phone (2012).

Output of `ls -l /system/bin/pm`. With `root` and non-root both returns this result.

```
# ls -l /system/bin/pm
-rwxr-xr-x root     root          191 2008-08-01 18:00 pm
```

Running `adb shell "/system/bin/pm install /sdcard/app-name.apk"` returns same error

> /sbin/sh: /system/bin/pm: not found

I also checked the `sh`'s permissions. `ls -la /system/bin/sh` returns this

```
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-12-06 12:00 sh -> mksh
```

Which looks a little unusual. Also `ls -la /system/bin/mksh` returns this

```
-rwxr-xr-x root     shell      153344 2008-08-01 18:00 mksh
```

I've also seen that running `mksh` instead of `sh` directly gives a root shell.

Comment: Looks strange. What custom ROM is it? Have you reported it already to the "ROM bakers" (i.e. at the place where the ROM came from, maybe the corresponding XDA thread)?

Comment: @Izzy No. I haven't reported to it and it seems the thread is too old now. You know this phone is old and thus the ROM also. It's [WolfRom v2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/sola-development/rom-wolf-romv2-t2424632)

Comment: Asking doesn't hurt. Some folks may still "watch" the thread – and if the problem lies in the ROM, you won't be the only one having experienced it. Worth trying, I'd say.

Comment: What does `ls -l /system/bin/pm` gives? Run it with root access.

Comment: What about running `adb shell "/system/bin/pm install /sdcard/app-name.apk"`? Does it work?

Comment: @Firelord I've updated the question.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman it returns same error. Check the update

Comment: @Izzy I'd do. But it seems its a trivial question..and weird one! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The question might look trivial, but finding the answer is not. And before you get me wrong: I'm not "sending you away", I just suggest "additional sources" ;)

Comment: @Izzy I got your tone. It really made me feel _home_ in this SE. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for the warm words – and yes, that's one of my goals (and besides it's something that made *me* feel home here when I started at SE years ago :) Fingers crossed, good luck!